# Nix: Querying packages' packages

Tags: package, nix

I can query available packages w/ `nix-env -qa [package]` but how can I look for optional packages (e.g. libraries) that depend on a primary package and can be loaded or installed separately? Example: Coq (`coq-8.6`) has packages `coqPackages_8_6.ssreflect` and `coqPackages_8_6.mathcomp` that I can get no information about in Nix AFAIK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally never use `nix-env -qa` because it is very slow.
Instead, when I'm looking for a top-level package (an application), I use http://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html.
When (like in your question), I'm looking for a non-top-level package, I use the auto-completion of `nix repl`. Run it with

```
nix repl '<nixpkgs>'
```

Now type for instance `coqPackages` and use auto-complete to see all the available versions. Type `coqPackages_8_6.` and use auto-complete to see all the available packages in this set.

Comment: Cool... BTW, `nix-env -iA nix-repl` gave "error: attribute ‘nix-repl’ in selection path ‘nix-repl’ not found" (but `nix-env -i nix-repl` worked)

Comment: Sorry I fixed my answer.

Comment: https://github.com/edolstra/nix-repl says that `nix-repl` is obsolete and one should use `nix repl` command these days, as the package was merged into Nix starting with version 1.12.

Answer (score 5):

`nix search` can also be used to search for packages. Caching all available packages is slow, but searching the cache is quite fast! Check `nix search --help`!