# Is ssrnat included in Coq 8.7?

Tags: coq, ssreflect

Coq 8.7 integrates the popular Ssreflect library. Its libraries can hence be imported in the following manner:

```
From Coq Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool.
```

However, when I try to import [`ssrnat`](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/doc/ssreflect-1.5/Ssreflect.ssrnat.html) it complains that it's `Unable to locate library ssrnat with prefix Coq`, and I cannot find ssrnat in the Coq distribution on disk either. Was `ssrnat` deliberately not included for some reason, or folder into another module, or is there just something wrong with my installation?

Comment: Does `From mathcomp Require Import ssrnat.` work?

Comment: That gives "Cannot find a physical path bound to logical path matching suffix <> and prefix mathcomp." (I don't have mathcomp installed. Should I?).

Comment: Despite the fact the Coq Refman mentions `ssrnat`, it's not in the standard library as of now (my installation has only `ssreflect`, `ssrfun`, and `ssrbool` in `$HOME/.opam/4.06.0/lib/coq/plugins/ssr` directory). So, yes you should install mathcomp. Incidentally, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955082/how-to-install-ssreflect-and-mathcomp-in-linux) might help with installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssrnat` is not included in the main Coq distribution, although some day we hope to provide an extended distribution where more libraries are available by default.

In Coq 8.7, only the tactic language itself `ssreflect` plus a few basic supporting libraries `ssrfun ssrbool` were included.

The reason we didn't include more is because `ssrnat` makes use of the math-comp mathematical hierarchy so this is a more "invasive" change.

Fortunately, thanks to the plugin being included, installing ssrnat is a very easy task.